# How to restore apps after a phone replacement?

Tags: apps, 7.5, lumia-900

- Carrier: ATT
- Nokia Lumia 900
- WP 7.5

Replaced inoperative phone with new one of the same type, I want to download my **paid** apps without paying again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the instructions here: [Delete or reinstall apps on windowsphone.com](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/how-to/wp7/apps/delete-apps-and-games)

> To reinstall apps from the web

- Open a web browser and go to www.windowsphone.com.
- Navigate to the My Phone dropdown menu, located in the upper-right
  corner of the screen, then sign in with the same Windows Live ID
  you've used on your phone.
- In the My Phone menu, click Purchase history.
- Under Purchase History, find the app you want to reinstall and click 
  Reinstall.
- Follow the instructions to reinstall the app. You might have to
  re-enter your Windows Live ID.

**Personal Notes:**

- Clicking on the reinstall link **failed** until I changed a phone setting to on:
  *Settings:find my phone:Connect to these features faster (may use more battery)*
- Clicking on multiple "Reinstall" links appears to stack requests, but
  seems to cause communication overloads.  Better to take more time and
  do individually.  At least failures are reported to the screen.

Comment: Actually you can find the app you want and click "buy". It will show you already paid the app and wont charge.

Comment: Forgot to mention, if you bought a specific carrier or brand app you must respect this. So if you had bought a Samsung app you can't download in a Nokia phone.

Comment: @Vitor Canova,  Thanks, good call. I was a bit chicken to click buy on a $19.95 app.  Especially good, because the larger apps seem to have trouble downloading from the web reinstall.